# How to simulate a non-White Gaussian process?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I am trying to numerically solve a second order stochastic differential equation.
Usually the noise is assumed to be Wiener Process which is white as far as I know.
Is it possible to use a Random Process which is Gaussian but not white?
And if so how can I pass it to the Ito process?

Comment: This seems more a math question than a Mathematica question.

Comment: A non-white noise would either have finite variance (e.g uniform, Laplace, triangular distributions) or infinite variance (e.g Cauchy). A solution to your SDE must have a continuous path with finite quadratic variation. If you use a finite variance source of noise in your Itô/Stratonovich integral then in the continuous limit that noise source might as well be normal because of the central limit theorem (accumulating lots of iid noises with finite variance), but with infinite variance noise sources it becomes difficult because over any time window it could shoot off to infinity.

Comment: A Wiener Process isn't white noise by the way - it's integrated white-noise i.e a continuous random walk or Brownian motion with finite quadratic variation a continuous path and infinitesimal 'jumps'. White noise on the other hand is the derivative. You can think of `WhiteNoiseProcess[]` as simply `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1]]` but with time coordinates added.